# In AngularJs, How to get Data inside the switch case to view?

Tags: angularjs

I want to display the total counts of logs, and I use growl to show the logs total.

but i want it to display it also in label, the problem is I don't have any idea how to get my regdata.length to display the total in view index.

I'm Noob. no YOUTUBE help me neither, getting data inside the Switch Case is hard for me, No idea.

//My Controller for index

```
var HomeController = function ($s, $mdDialog, service, growl, $linq) {

    $s.growl = function (type,count) {

        console.log('type',type);

        var config = {};
        switch (type) {
            case "success":
                growl.success("Logs Without Problem: " + count, { disableCountDown: true, ttl: 3000 });
                break;
            case "info":
                growl.info("Total logs: " + count, { disableCountDown: true, ttl: 3000 });
                break;

            default:
                growl.error("Logs with Problem: " + count, { disableCountDown: true, ttl: 3000 });
        }
    }


    //Switch Condition
    $s.filter = function (d) {

        if ($s.mainData) {

            switch (d) {
                case 'wErr':
                    $s.regdata = $linq.Enumerable().From($s.mainData).Where(function (x) { return x.OK_Latest == 'No' }).ToArray();
                    $s.growl('error', $s.regdata.length)
                    break;
                case 'noErr':
                    $s.regdata = $linq.Enumerable().From($s.mainData).Where(function (x) { return x.OK_Latest == 'Yes' }).ToArray();
                    $s.growl('success', $s.regdata.length)
                    break;
                case 'def':
                    $s.regdata = $s.mainData;
                    $s.growl('info', $s.regdata.length)
                    break;
            }
            console.log('req', $s.regdata);
        }
    }
```

I have 3 condition in switch case.display in view the total logs each.

Comment: sorry for my grammar in advance.

Comment: you can do by adding return inside cases.

Comment: i did it. thanks! @georgeawg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//thank for giving me idea @georgeawg

var init = (function () {
        $s.sColumn = '';
        $s.reverse = false;
        $s.loader = false;
        $s.currentTbl = '';
        $s.isNulltblNo = [];
        $s.isNulltblYes = [];
        $s.successCount = 0;
        $s.infoCount = 0;
        $s.errorCount = 0;
    }());

    $s.growl = function (type, count) {

        console.log('type', type);

        var config = {};
        switch (type) {
            case "success":
                growl.success("Logs Without Problem: " + count, { disableCountDown: true, ttl: 3000 });
                $s.successCount = count;

                break;
            case "info":
                growl.info("Total logs: " + count, { disableCountDown: true, ttl: 3000 });
                $s.infoCount = count;
                break;
            default:
                growl.error("Logs with Problem: " + count, { disableCountDown: true, ttl: 3000 });
                $s.errorCount = count;
        }
    }
```